# Get Webpack to warn about missing packages when building

Tags: javascript, webpack

Once in a while, I see something like the following in my bundle file:

```
var _TodoListContainer = __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"containers/TodoListContainer.react\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));
```

How can I get Webpack to warn about missing files when it's building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [webpack node API](https://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html#the-short-way) provides you with a stats object in the callback:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

// returns a Compiler instance
webpack({
    // configuration
}, function(err, stats) {
    // ...
});
```

This object has all the information you need and you can use it for programatically [handling errors](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/node.js-api#error-handling):

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
webpack({
    // configuration
}, function(err, stats) {
    if(err)
        return handleFatalError(err);
    var jsonStats = stats.toJson();
    if(jsonStats.errors.length > 0)
        return handleSoftErrors(jsonStats.errors);
    if(jsonStats.warnings.length > 0)
        handleWarnings(jsonStats.warnings);
    successfullyCompiled();
});
```

If you are using the CLI with Webpack's default configuration it should provide you with feedback about missing dependencies out of the box. You can use the command line flag [--display-error-details](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#display-error-details) for specifics.

Comment: I'm using Gulp and `stream.on('error', util.log)` to handle errors. In this case, no errors where thrown.

Comment: Errors will be thrown only on fatal errors. You can use the task [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html#normal-compilation) and check the stats object passed in callback as I have illustrated in the last example of my answer.